# HardhatError: HH101: Hardhat was set to use chain id 11155111, but connected to a chain with id 1

Tags: hardhat, sepolia

//hardhat.config.js

````js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {},
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.8",
}'''
/// The code is returning the following error below
```error
HardhatError: HH101: Hardhat was set to use chain id 11155111, but connected to a chain with id 1.
    at ChainIdValidatorProvider.request
````

// Yesterday morning l was able to deploy to a Sepolia network then it started returning this error. I have been on this problem for more than 18hours can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the right RPC url for your sepolia network. For example, An Ethereum mainnet rpc URL from alchemy is not going to work on the sepolia network.
I encountered this issue too but I managed to fix it by using a public rpc url that you can find on https://chainlist.org/chain/11155111. I used: `https://sepolia.gateway.tenderly.co`